# Run function on observable subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm attempting to write a custom component that can bind to an observable being passed in through an input and show/hide elements based on the state of the observable. What I'd like to be able to do is something like:

```
@Input() observable: Observable<any>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.observable.onSubscribe(() => {
        // show element, run logic on start;
    });
    this.observable.onCompleteOrNext(() => {
        // hide element, run logic on end;
    });
}
```

After pouring over the rxjs documentation, I've found that with [let](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/let.md) I could do something like:

```
this.observable.let((o: Observable) => {
    // run logic.
    return o;
});
```

But this seems like a bit of a hack, and I also can't figure out how to then run something when the observable completes. I expect the observables to be async, such as an HTTP request, but this component needs to handle it either way.

For the observable completing, I assumed I would be able to do something like the below with the [do](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md) function:

```
this.observable.do(() => {
    // run logic when observable completes.
    // not getting called.
});
```

But, unless the `do` function is defined on the observable creation, this is not getting called.

I'm aware Angular2 allows binding the view directly to observables, but I also need the ability to run logic based on the observable, not just show/hide view elements.

My googlefoo is failing me and the rxjs documentation isn't being very enlightening, but I feel like this should be a fairly easy thing to do. Perhaps I am approaching it wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why not just `subscribe()` in `ngOnInit` and specify the `next`, `error` and `complete` callbacks right there? `this.observable.subscribe(next=>{}, err=>{}, ()=>{})`

Comment: Well, I don't want this component to subscribe to the observable, as it won't be doing anything with the data returned. It's more just supposed to be in a state based on other subscribers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Where would you subscribe? The parent component?

Comment: @BeetleJuice, most likely. If that had to be a restraint I think it would be a reasonable one.

Comment: You can't do this thing with observable (I guess *customized* Subject should be provided instead of observable in order to do that). And most likely, you shouldn't. This requirement *I don't want this component to subscribe to the observable, as it won't be doing anything with the data returned. It's more just supposed to be in a state based on other subscribers* doesn't sound reasonable. Just `subscribe`, it doesn't oblige you to do anything with data.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide hook methods within the child component:

```
export class ChildComponent {
    onSubscribe(){}
    onNext(){}
    onComplete(){}
}
```

In the parent component, you can use `ViewChild` to get a reference to the `ChildComponent`, then subscribe to the observable and call the hook methods at key points:

- once you've subscribed
- when the observable emits
- when the observable completes

.

```
export class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChild('child') child:ChildComponent;
    ...
    this.observable.subscribe(
        next => this.child.onNext(),
        err => {},
        () => this.child.onComplete()
    );
    this.child.onSubscribe()
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iICFaZfIqapJJchQxPam?p=preview)

Comment: This is a really good suggestion, I think I've decided to take a slightly different route with it. I'm creating a wrapper for observables that I'll pass around instead. When I get the implementation done I'll share.